# Xamarin forms Send Email Directly

Tags: xamarin.forms

How can I send an Email in Xamarin Forms without an Email App,i would to send an Email Directly when i click on a Button !

Thank you for your help :-))

Comment: You would need to connect directly to an e-mail server to do this.  The OS won't let you compose an e-mail using the user's account without user interaction.

Comment: I  use SMTP Server but I need the reference System.Net.Mail ,I add it but it's empty and no contain MailMessage for example,i have               " The type name 'MailMessage' could not be found in the namespace "System.Net.mail". This type has been forwarded to assembly Consider adding a reference to that assembly".

Comment: It seems work on MyProject.Droid and MyProject.iOS but why not in MyProject.Portable because i work on it

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help you:

If you can't add the System.Net.Mail package to your project, I usually call a WebApi, or a simple php file, and there(in the php file / WebApi like ASP.NET MVC) you have to implement not in the Xamarin side. https://github.com/officialdoniald/PetBellies/blob/master/PetBellies/PetBellies/BLL/ViewModel/SignupPageViewModel.cs

Otherwise you can create a .NET Standard Xamarin.Forms Project and you can add the System.Net.Mail package to your project.

Comment: Hello Bence. Please embed the entire answer directly into the SO post.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look here - this answer applies to you as well.
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/184222/#Comment_184222

The PLC does not implement all system classes, only the OS specific classes does (like iOS or Android), because the various OS'es implement their systems differently.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: The link does not work anymore.